# Jira NextGen: How to send issues into "completed" state?

Tags: jira

We use **Jira Next-Gen** with Atlassians cloud-hosting.

I moved Issues from "in progress" into "Done" state. However, when I want to close the current Sprint, Jira still reports all Issues as "open" and asks me to transfer them over into the next sprint.

Within the **Jira Next-gen** project there is no option to "close" an issue.

If "done" is not the right state to complete an issue, how can I achieve that?

[image]

Comment: Try to put them into Closed! We had such fun as well... if that doesn't wok, then maybe those issues are part of a story that is not done yet? Also it can be that there is some time left on the issues as remaining time!

Comment: Under the 'done' status, there should be something called 'unresolved'. I think sometimes depending on your configuration, you need to manually resolve them.

Comment: Thx for the hint. Within the **Jira Next-gen** project there is no option to "close" an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking your Board for the active sprint. The columns in the board represent the available statuses and only the last column (rightmost) is the 'complete' state.

Do you have a status to the right of 'Done' on the board? If so you can try dragging 'Done' to the far right which should fix your issue.